# NuMI beam energy spectrum

Tags: neutrinos

At what energy value do we get the maximum neutrino flux from NuMI beam? Could one fix this energy arbitrarily ( of course with the range of NuMI source) at a value yielding the maximum neutrino flux ?

Comment: For those who might not know that's $\nu$'s from the Main Injector at Fermilab.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.